# Office 365 Public Calendar example

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I need to create a public calendar on Office 365 and show its events on a website using c#/Microsoft Graph API. The only examples I've found so far talk about mailbox/calendar access for a normal/authenticated user. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/dotnet-tutorial

**Is OAuth required for this scenario?** If not, how to access the calendar programmatically using just username/password of a service account?

Comment: SO needs to require a comment for voting down stating the reason! At least tell me what else you'd like to know??

Comment: What have your tried? Instead of linking to examples, it would be more helpful to see what _you_ have tried and where it's going wrong :)

Comment: @Symon Do you want me to just jump into coding or at least get the concept correct first? Do I really need OAuth for service account? Have you ever written an Office 365 public calendar code?

Comment: Getting the concept first is the correct start. However, You asked for a reason for downvotes, and not supplying what you've done code-wise is a popular reason to downvote. You also have no **question** within your post, only statements, which would be another reason for the downvotes. I have not personally written anything for Office 365. Was just trying to give some pointers for your post in order to avoid downvotes :)

Comment: @Symon clarified the post using a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*All* calls to Microsoft Graph require a valid access token (i.e. OAuth).

Comment: Just posting here for future reference: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_overview